# Syntax to create unique composite column - Android SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have this `onCreate` method in my `SQLiteOpenHelper`
class, and I would like to add a unique constraint on these two columns (composite unique columns):

- `SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_TITLE`
- `SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_RELEASEDATE`

But I am getting an error:

> Cannot resolve method UNIQUE

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    final String SQL_CREATE_SONG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + SongContract.SongEntry.TABLE_SONG + " (" +
        SongContract.SongEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_RELEASEDATE + " INTEGER, " +
        UNIQUE(SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_TITLE, SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_RELEASEDATE) +
        SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_RATING + " TEXT);";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_SONG_TABLE);
}
```

What is the correct syntax to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the corrrect syntax after playing around sqllite:

final String SQL_CREATE_SONG_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + SongContract.SongEntry.TABLE_SONG + " (" +
            SongContract.SongEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_RELEASEDATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_RATING + " TEXT, " +  "UNIQUE" + "(" +
            SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_TITLE + "," +  SongContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_RELEASEDATE + ") " + ");";